# File deleted in git

Tags: git

Scenario
Main repo lets say it as X | upstream; 
Fork of the above repo X | origin

A branch Y which is there in both upstream and origin.
Problem:

1. A particular file is getting deleted when I go from branch Y to Z and come back to Y in my local (All the time the branch is always present in the  upstream Y branch and i am committing and pushing code in branches including in branch Y)
2. Then i take the file from the upstream (copy it) and commit again and start switching branches and the problem starts happening again.

Any idea why this would be happening? It is consistent even if somebody else does it the file is missing. And it happens only with a single file.

**EDIT**: 
I did a git pull upstream Y . It said Already up to date and surprisingly the file is back. And I am pretty sure that it was not there before. The same thing happened with somebody else also when i asked them to try the scenario. The file was not there when we first did git checkout upstream/Y -b Y and when we did a pull upstream Y the file was back. Is this a bug in git?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your local branch `Y` is out of sync with your `origin/Y` branch.

If anything *other* than the following is the result of `git status`:

```
$ git status

On branch Y
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/Y'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Then you can probably reset `Y` to the state of `origin/Y`:

```
git checkout Y; git reset --hard origin/Y
```

*Note:* that this will remove any local changes you have done.

If you have accidentally removed the file in your local branch `Y` and would like to restore only that file, you can do so using:

```
git checkout origin/Y /path/to/file
```

After that you can commit the change

```
git commit -m "Add back accidentally removed file" /path/to/file
```

Then you might potentially want to rewrite your local history (see `git rebase -i` and `git commit --amend`)

Comment: It's probably easier if you actually showed the exact operations and their output rather than paraphrasing.

If you knew what part of the process were important you would already know what the problem was :)

Comment: There was nothing unusual in while doing it. The only problem was that one moment the file was there and the other it was not (after switching branches). I am not able to reproduce it now . But thanks for the answer.